# How may I achieve the effect of insetting a concave n-gon?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]

The picture above shows the outer walls of a house I'm modeling. The walls of the main house (highlighted orange) need to have an inner layer of insulation, which is half as thick as the present walls.

Ideally, I could create an n-gon with the selected vertices and then do an inset to get the geometry I want. However, an n-gon cannot be created from the selected vertices. Or at least, no n-gon is created when I hit [F].

Is there some way I can avoid a lot tedious vertex shuffling?

Comment: This question is a tad unclear but firstly, blender can fill n-gons so its a problem that blender wont do it here, and also, insetting is done with I as im sure you already know so why dont you do multiple insets to create the geometry?

Comment: Probably a case for [Offset Edges](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Modeling/offset_edges) addon

Answer (score 1):

An alternative and perhaps more accurate method would be to use the Solidify modifier twice.

Trace out the outside walls outer edge ground plan then add a Solidify modifier to create the inner edges of these walls. In the example below I set my walls to have 0.2m thickness and selected only the **Even Thickness** option. The solidify modifier needs faces to work with so the outer walls were extruded up 1 meter.

After applying this first modifier add a second. This will be for the insulation thickness. In object mode apply this modifier.
 The second modifier created unwanted faces ouside of the outer walls so these will need to be deleted. Also delete the extruded edges to return to a simple 2D ground plan.

[image: **enter image description here**]

With Snapping to vertex enabled use extrude to add the missing inner wall and insulation.

[image]